Definitions of polynomials $F(x):=f(x+c)$ and $G(x):=f(cx)$ if $c\in Z(R)$
The author in the paper "Null ideals of subsets of matrix rings over fields" says (in page 6) that: when $c$ is central in a ring $R$ (not necessarily commutative), the  polynomials $F(x):=f(x+c)$ and $G(x):=f(cx)$ are defined as in the ordinary commutative case. Moreover, for all $r\in R$, we have $F(r)=f(r+c)$ and $G(r)=f(cr)$".
Why does $c\in R$ must be in $Z(R)$ to define $F$ and $G$? What is the point of that?

Essentially, to have a nice polynomial ring, you want your indeterminates to commute with the coefficients. If this is not true, you get a dichotomy between polynomials as elements of a ring and their associated evaluation maps. In particular, it might not be true that $F(r)=f(r+c)$. To take an example, borrowed from the link below, consider $f(x)=ix-xi\in \Bbb{H}[x]$. By definition of this polynomial ring, $f$ is the zero polynomial. However, if we naïvely allow $F(x):= f(x+j)$, we see that $F(x)=ix-xi+ji-ij$. As a polynomial, this is $F(x)=ji-ij = -2k$, and evaluating this at any point $r$ is non-zero. However, it is also the evaluation of $f(x)$ at $r+j$, and since $f(x)$ is the zero polynomial, it should be zero.
You can consider it as a notational issue; what does $f(x+c)$ even mean? The answer is, it only really makes sense if $c$ commutes with coefficients.
See also Do polynomials make sense over non-commutative rings?

I got it well. Thank you very much for your nice explanation. Appreciate your help.
